# Entity Framework cannot update a column; getting System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

In asp.net web api I am using Entity Framework to communicate with database. Here I am trying to update a single column in the a table.

```
public HttpResponseMessage ActivateAccount(string activation_code, string userMail)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activation_code) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userMail))
   {
      Account activateAcc =  db.Accounts.Where(user => user.AccMail == userMail && user.ConfirmToken == activation_code).SingleOrDefault();

      if (activateAcc != null)
      {
         activateAcc.IsActive = true;
         db.SaveChanges();
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "account activated");
      }
      else
      {
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "invalid account");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "missing user Mail or activation code");
   }
}
```

but at that statement

```
Account activateAcc =  db.Accounts.Where(user => user.AccMail == userMail && user.ConfirmToken == activation_code).SingleOrDefault();
```

I am getting an exception of type `System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException` with this inner exception

> Error 3002: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:Potential runtime violation of table Account's keys (Account.AccID): Columns (Account.AccID) are mapped to EntitySet Accounts's properties (Accounts.AccID) on the conceptual side but they do not form the EntitySet's key properties (Accounts.AccID, Accounts.AccMail, Accounts.AccName, Accounts.AccPassword, Accounts.IsActive, Accounts.IsAdmin).\r\n\r\nAccPlusModel.msl(19,10) : error 3002: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 19:Potential runtime violation of table TansactionCategory's keys (TansactionCategory.CatID): Columns (TansactionCategory.CatID) are mapped to EntitySet TansactionCategories's properties (TansactionCategories.CatID) on the conceptual side but they do not form the EntitySet's key properties (TansactionCategories.CatAccount, TansactionCategories.CatColor, TansactionCategories.CatID, TansactionCategories.CatName)

Answer (score 0):

entity framework designer had identified all columns in the table as a primary key by as first when i set up framework i had no PK so even if i set PK in sql server and update mode it will stay the same so i have to edit model my self

Comment: perhaps dropping and creatign the model again will be faster